# Creating a schema synonym in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, schema

I read about the parameter `_enable_schema_synonyms` which allows a user to create schema synonyms. However, to enable the parameter it would require a DB reboot.

Are there any negatives to enabling this parameter? Is it worth the reboot?

Answer (score 1):

> Unless it's an officially documented parameter, you shouldn't use it unless directed to by Oracle support. ([Alex Poole](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/847/alex-poole))

> Setting and using undocumented parameters unless Oracle Support specifically tells you to is almost always a bad idea -- they're undocumented for a reason. Doing so as a junior DBA with no senior DBA available is a really, really bad idea because you're going to be stuck when something goes south. A couple of issues with the parameter are [shown here](https://blog.dbi-services.com/create-schema-synonym-in-oracle-unsupported-feature/) but there are likely others. ([Justin Cave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/555/justin-cave)).